# $(S \circ T)^t = S^t \circ T^t$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to understand an elementary idea in the transpose of a linear operator, namely that if $S \in L_K(U,V)$ and $T \in L_K(V,W)$ for vector spaces $U,V,W$ over a field $K$ that

$(S \circ T)^t = T^t \circ S^t$.

So it seems I should first take a linear form say $g:W^* \rightarrow U^*$
then $(S \circ T)^t (g) = g(S \circ T)$. Here is where I am stuck. Any hints/tips appreciated.

Comment: This is false. The compositions on the left and right usually won't even simultaneously make sense.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan sorry typo.